# What kind of Traveling Salesman Problem is this?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms

I'm trying to solve a problem which I think is a variant of the Travelling Salesman Problem (TSP), but I'm not sure which. Here is a high-level scenario:

> - A salesman has a territory made up of streets.
> - He has to travel all of those streets, but he can also drive on streets outside the territory if need be.
> - A number of the streets are one-way and let's assume it's
>     impossible to visit every street without traveling outside the
>     territory for at least some distance.
> - What's the shortest way to visit all required streets?

Because the street network is directed this seems like [asymmetric TSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Asymmetric_TSP), but I'm not sure how to account for the fact that only a subset of the edges are required, while others are still allowed. Is this just a matter of applying weights to the edges? Is there a different problem class I should look into?

Ultimately I'm trying to write a computer program to do this, and really just looking for the right algorithm/approach. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is a "city block" a point, or is it an _area_ where the salesman just needs to visit _some_ point in that area?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity - a city block in this case is a street segment. He must travel down the entire segment, from one intersection to another.

Comment: This a variant of the postman problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_inspection_problem.  There is some chance of it having an efficient solution, but it depends on the particulars as some variants are NP-complete.

Comment: @ErickWong: In particular, the problem here mixes directed and undirected edges, and the Wikipedia article states _that_ is an NP-complete variant.